# Menu disappear after refresh page Angular

Tags: angular

I have an app with angular, it display the menu after successfully logged in work great.

So i have GlobalEventsManager

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalEventsManager {

    private _showNavBar: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
    public showNavBarEmitter: Observable<boolean> = this._showNavBar.asObservable();

    constructor() {}

    showNavBar(ifShow: boolean) {
        this._showNavBar.next(ifShow);
    }

}
```

And in menu component

```
this.globalEventsManager.showNavBarEmitter.subscribe((mode)=>{
            if (mode !== null) {
                this.showNavBar = mode;
            }
        });
```

And In login

```
 this.globalEventsManager.showNavBar(true);
    this.router_.navigate(['welcome']);
```

I put menu inside app.component

```
<app-menu></app-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So menu work great, but after refresh page menu **disappear**, in console log i get console.log(mode) null.

So how can i resolve this issue and thanks

Comment: Where do you put your menu, inside component or out of router-outler ?

Comment: @ThienHoang i edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal that after page refresh `_showNavBar` value is being set to `null` again. That's because the whole `GlobalEventsManager` has run again. To resolve that, you need to check whether the user is logged in or not (for example inside constructor in `GlobalEventsManager` and then set `_showNavBar` value once more.

Best place for checking whether user is logged in or not would be some global component.